# WIndows 10 won't hibernate (hibernation is turned on)

Tags: windows, windows-10, hibernate

I can't get my Windows 10 machine to hibernate. Hibernation is turned on in Power Settings and I executed the following command on top of it just to make sure:

```
powercfg -h on
```

[image: Power settings]

When I select Hibernate from the shut down menu the system turns off the monitor and it looks like it starts to hibernate but then after a few seconds the monitor is turned back on and a see the lock screen. I've tried this many times already.

I'm using the Balanced plan and I also restored its settings to defaults.

Why doesn't it work?

Windows version: 10.0.15063 Build 15063

Comment: Run [powercfg -energy](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/) and post the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your machine is waking up almost immediately.

I had the same issue on my home PC and fixed it by following this Guide:

[How to Prevent Your Computer From Waking Up Accidentally](https://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/)

My network adapter was set to ***allow this device to wake the computer***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Open the Registry Editor by pressing Win + R and typing regedit in the Run box.

In the left pane of Registry Editor, navigate to the following
location:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power

Close Registry Editor and restart the computer to apply the changes.

Source
[1]: https://www.top-password.com/blog/2-options-to-enable-disable-hibernate-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows 11. Surprisingly, resetting hibernation seems to have fixed the problem. In cmd as administrator:

```
powercfg –h off
powercfg –h on
```

I had tried just the on command by itself and that didn't work, but doing off then on did (computers are weird).

This was suggested by Microsoft support: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-11-hibernate-not-working/a7510603-a8d0-4eb2-a01f-89d78ba44732

Answer (score 0):

Some programs can prevent your pc from hibernating by doing what you are describing exactly. I suggest you make sure you don't have any emulators on like bluestacks, LDplayer, Memu.

for me running LDPlayer android emulator created this problem. I could only hibernate after I close it.

you could also check what process is keeping your computer awake by running cmd as administrator and typing:

```
powercfg -requests
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).